# I get incompatible types in the assignment?

Tags: iphone, c

```
int k[4] = {1,2,3,4};
int kk[4];  
kk=k;
```

I get incompatible types in the assignment??
Do I have to loop and assign each value in the array, or is there an easier way?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop, or use a library call.

One option would be `memcpy(kk, k, sizeof(k));`. For this you must `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: I would advice against using sizeof(k), but rather use sizeof(kk) instead - this insures that no matter what, you will never overflow the memory bounds allocated for kk in the event that k gets resized at a later time.  Finding missing data out of an array is easier to debug than memory overwrites.

Comment: @Phil: agreed. I used sizeof(k) as it shows the intention of "copy the array k", but your advice is very true.

Comment: strcpy is not at all suitable in this specific example since you are not working with strings (character arrays) and you example is with integer arrays. strcpy is generally bad news anyways since it relies on the presence of a terminating null and will happily overwrite past the destination boundary if none is found. strncpy is safe. For your original question, memcpy is definitely the way to go.

Comment: It is as bad to copy more data from the source than there is in the source as it is to copy more data to the target than there is room for in the target.  So, given a suitable `MIN()` function or macro, you might sensibly use: `memcpy(kk, k, MIN(sizeof(k), sizeof(kk)));`.  You also have to be careful, though, if one of the arrays is a parameter to the function, rather than a local array or a global array whose definition is visible (as opposed to a global array identified by an `extern` declaration).  For parameters and external arrays, `sizeof()` yields the 'wrong' result (for this context).

Comment: With memcpy, do I need to include string.h since it is integers?  That is why I assumed strcpy or strncpy. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Arrays don't behave like primitive data types in C. You have to loop over the array and assign each value. You can't just assign one array to another (especially since kk is really an int pointer). Not too hard though:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    kk[i] = k[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no copy assignment of good old C arrays. So yes, you have to loop through and copy each element.